# java.io.IOException : The filename or extension is too long Grails 4.0.8

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, grails, groovy

I am creating a project in Grails 4.0.8 (Windows 10)(Java 11)
After adding all dependencies, I get this error.

```
java.io.IOException: The filename or extension is too long
```

I searched the whole StackOverflow and tried to use the solutions but none works.

All lead to this error message.

```
Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
> Main class name has not been configured and it could not be resolved
```

Also, I have some dependencies in build.gradle and some of them in /libs as *.jar

Currently my build.gradle looks like this(with the solution applied)
What have i done as solution is written in comments as //_____ below is part of the solution

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.github.erdi.webdriver-binaries:webdriver-binaries-gradle-plugin:2.0"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:7.0.4"
        classpath "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:3.2.4"
//        classpath group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml-schemas', version: '4.1.2'
//        classpath group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '4.1.2'
//        classpath group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '4.1.2'
    }
}



version "0.1"
group "com.main.projectname"

apply plugin:"eclipse"
apply plugin:"idea"
apply plugin:"war"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin:"com.github.erdi.webdriver-binaries"
apply plugin:"com.bertramlabs.asset-pipeline"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-gsp"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    maven {url "http://tools-artifactory.tetris.ideasdev.int:82/artifactory/repo"}
    //for external-config
    maven { url "https://oss.jfrog.org/repo/" }
}

configurations {
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
}

dependencies {
    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.grails:grails-core:4.0.8"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    compile "org.grails:grails-logging"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-rest"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-databinding"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-i18n"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-services"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-url-mappings"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-interceptors"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:async"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:events"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:gsp"
    compileOnly "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-groovy"
    console "org.grails:grails-console"
    profile "org.grails.profiles:web"
    runtime "org.glassfish.web:el-impl:2.1.2-b03"
    runtime "com.h2database:h2:1.4.199"
    runtime "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc"
    runtime "javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1"
    runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails"
    testCompile "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-groovy"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-gorm-testing-support"
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-web-testing-support"
    testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"
    testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver"
    testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-api:3.14.0"
    testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:3.14.0"
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:3.14.0"
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:3.14.0"

//    User added
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:external-config:2.0.0'

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:grails-shiro:3.3'
//    implementation group: 'com.github.ManifestClasspath', name: 'com.github.ManifestClasspath.gradle.plugin', version: '0.1.0-RELEASE', ext: 'pom'
    implementation group: 'org.grails.plugins', name: 'quartz', version: '2.0.13'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-jms', version: '5.3.4'
    implementation group: 'commons-dbcp', name: 'commons-dbcp', version: '1.4'
    implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.8.0'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context-support', version: '3.2.18.RELEASE'
    implementation "opensymphony:quartz-all:1.6.3"
//    implementation group: 'org.quartz-scheduler', name: 'quartz', version: '2.3.2'

    implementation group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml-schemas', version: '4.1.2'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '4.1.2'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '4.1.2'


    runtime group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml-schemas', version: '4.1.2'
    runtime group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '4.1.2'
    runtime group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '4.1.2'

//    implementation group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.23'

    //Depencencies from /lib found directly from maven
//    implementation group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-entitymanager', version: '5.2.1.Final'
//    implementation group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'sqljdbc4', version: '4.2.6225.100'

//    implementation group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: '1.2' //1.15
//    implementation group: 'javax.activation', name: 'activation', version: '1.1' //1.1.1
//    implementation group: 'org.apache.axis', name: 'axis', version: '1.4'
//    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-collections4', version: '4.1'//4.4




}


//Task below is part of solution
task pathingJar(type: Jar) {
    dependsOn configurations.runtime
    appendix = 'pathing'
    doFirst {
        manifest {
            attributes "Class-Path": configurations.runtime.files.collect {
                it.toURL().toString().replaceFirst(/file:\/+/, '/')
            }.join(' ')
        }
    }
}
bootRun {

    //Line below is part of solution
    dependsOn pathingJar


    ignoreExitValue true
    jvmArgs(
        '-Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always',
        '-noverify',
        '-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1',
        '-Xmx1024m')
    sourceResources sourceSets.main
    String springProfilesActive = 'spring.profiles.active'
    systemProperty springProfilesActive, System.getProperty(springProfilesActive)
    //doFirst below is part of solution
    doFirst {
        classpath = files("$buildDir/classes/main", "$buildDir/resources/main", pathingJar.archivePath)
    }
}

tasks.withType(GroovyCompile) {
    configure(groovyOptions) {
        forkOptions.jvmArgs = ['-Xmx1024m']
    }
}

webdriverBinaries {
    chromedriver '2.45.0'
    geckodriver '0.24.0'
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    systemProperty "geb.env", System.getProperty('geb.env')
    systemProperty "geb.build.reportsDir", reporting.file("geb/integrationTest")
    systemProperty "webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty('webdriver.chrome.driver')
    systemProperty "webdriver.gecko.driver", System.getProperty('webdriver.gecko.driver')
}


assets {
    minifyJs = true
    minifyCss = true
}


//task pathingJar(type: Jar , dependsOn: 'cleanPathingJar') {
///**
// * If the gradle_user_home env var has been set to
// * C:\ on a Win7 machine, we may not have permission to write the jar to
// * this directory, so we will write it to the caches subdir instead.
// * This assumes a caches subdir containing the jars
// * will always exist.
// */
//    gradleUserHome = new File(gradle.getGradleUserHomeDir(), "caches")
//
//    relativeClasspathEntries = configurations.compile.files.collect {
//        new File(gradleUserHome.getAbsolutePath()).toURI().
//                relativize(new File(it.getAbsolutePath()).toURI()).getPath()
//    }
//    appendix = "pathing"
//    destinationDir = gradleUserHome
//    doFirst {
//        manifest {
//            attributes "Class-Path": relativeClasspathEntries.join(" ")
//        }
//    }
//}
//
//compileGroovy {
//    dependsOn(pathingJar)
//    classpath = files(pathingJar.archivePath)
//}
```

My Original build.gradle is as below:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.github.erdi.webdriver-binaries:webdriver-binaries-gradle-plugin:2.0"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:7.0.4"
        classpath "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:3.2.4"
//        classpath group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml-schemas', version: '4.1.2'
//        classpath group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '4.1.2'
//        classpath group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '4.1.2'
    }
}



version "0.1"
group "com.main.projectname"

apply plugin:"eclipse"
apply plugin:"idea"
apply plugin:"war"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin:"com.github.erdi.webdriver-binaries"
apply plugin:"com.bertramlabs.asset-pipeline"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-gsp"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    maven {url "http://tools-artifactory.tetris.ideasdev.int:82/artifactory/repo"}
    //for external-config
    maven { url "https://oss.jfrog.org/repo/" }
}

configurations {
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
}

dependencies {
    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.grails:grails-core:4.0.8"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    compile "org.grails:grails-logging"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-rest"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-databinding"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-i18n"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-services"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-url-mappings"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-interceptors"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:async"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:events"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:gsp"
    compileOnly "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-groovy"
    console "org.grails:grails-console"
    profile "org.grails.profiles:web"
    runtime "org.glassfish.web:el-impl:2.1.2-b03"
    runtime "com.h2database:h2:1.4.199"
    runtime "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc"
    runtime "javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1"
    runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails"
    testCompile "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-groovy"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-gorm-testing-support"
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-web-testing-support"
    testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"
    testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver"
    testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-api:3.14.0"
    testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:3.14.0"
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:3.14.0"
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:3.14.0"

//    User added
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:external-config:2.0.0'

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:grails-shiro:3.3'
//    implementation group: 'com.github.ManifestClasspath', name: 'com.github.ManifestClasspath.gradle.plugin', version: '0.1.0-RELEASE', ext: 'pom'
    implementation group: 'org.grails.plugins', name: 'quartz', version: '2.0.13'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-jms', version: '5.3.4'
    implementation group: 'commons-dbcp', name: 'commons-dbcp', version: '1.4'
    implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.8.0'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context-support', version: '3.2.18.RELEASE'
    implementation "opensymphony:quartz-all:1.6.3"
//    implementation group: 'org.quartz-scheduler', name: 'quartz', version: '2.3.2'

    implementation group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml-schemas', version: '4.1.2'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '4.1.2'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '4.1.2'


    runtime group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml-schemas', version: '4.1.2'
    runtime group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '4.1.2'
    runtime group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '4.1.2'

//    implementation group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.23'

    //Depencencies from /lib found directly from maven
//    implementation group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-entitymanager', version: '5.2.1.Final'
//    implementation group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'sqljdbc4', version: '4.2.6225.100'

//    implementation group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: '1.2' //1.15
//    implementation group: 'javax.activation', name: 'activation', version: '1.1' //1.1.1
//    implementation group: 'org.apache.axis', name: 'axis', version: '1.4'
//    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-collections4', version: '4.1'//4.4
}

bootRun {
    ignoreExitValue true
    jvmArgs(
        '-Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always', 
        '-noverify', 
        '-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1',
        '-Xmx1024m')
    sourceResources sourceSets.main
    String springProfilesActive = 'spring.profiles.active'
    systemProperty springProfilesActive, System.getProperty(springProfilesActive)
}

tasks.withType(GroovyCompile) {
    configure(groovyOptions) {
        forkOptions.jvmArgs = ['-Xmx1024m']
    }
}

webdriverBinaries {
    chromedriver '2.45.0'
    geckodriver '0.24.0'
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    systemProperty "geb.env", System.getProperty('geb.env')
    systemProperty "geb.build.reportsDir", reporting.file("geb/integrationTest")
    systemProperty "webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty('webdriver.chrome.driver')
    systemProperty "webdriver.gecko.driver", System.getProperty('webdriver.gecko.driver')
}


assets {
    minifyJs = true
    minifyCss = true
}


//task pathingJar(type: Jar , dependsOn: 'cleanPathingJar') {
///**
// * If the gradle_user_home env var has been set to
// * C:\ on a Win7 machine, we may not have permission to write the jar to
// * this directory, so we will write it to the caches subdir instead.
// * This assumes a caches subdir containing the jars
// * will always exist.
// */
//    gradleUserHome = new File(gradle.getGradleUserHomeDir(), "caches")
//
//    relativeClasspathEntries = configurations.compile.files.collect {
//        new File(gradleUserHome.getAbsolutePath()).toURI().
//                relativize(new File(it.getAbsolutePath()).toURI()).getPath()
//    }
//    appendix = "pathing"
//    destinationDir = gradleUserHome
//    doFirst {
//        manifest {
//            attributes "Class-Path": relativeClasspathEntries.join(" ")
//        }
//    }
//}
//
//compileGroovy {
//    dependsOn(pathingJar)
//    classpath = files(pathingJar.archivePath)
//}
```

I have tried the following solution but none worked or led to same Main class not configured error mentioned at top

1)
[Shorten classpath in intellij](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRAS2.png)

2. 

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.github.viswaramamoorthy:gradle-util-plugins:0.1.0-RELEASE"
    }
}
...
apply plugin: 'ManifestClasspath'
```

3. 

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.4.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id "com.github.ManifestClasspath" version "0.1.0-RELEASE"       
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = 'com.example.demo.Application'
dependencies {

 }
```

Comment: Where exactly and when do you get this error? Does run by Gradle from command line work?

Comment: @Andrey I am using a grails project in IntelliJ Idea. I use grails run-app which basically calls gradle build and starts the grails app on localhost. When i run grails run-app, this error comes. Also, Grails uses spring Boot as its application server.

Comment: This Gradle issue is related: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1989

Answer (score 2):

Try using this Gradle plugin: [com.virgo47.ClasspathJar](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.virgo47.ClasspathJar).

Comment: This is another similar plugin https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.github.ManifestClasspath, this did not work for me, but what you suggested com.virgo47.ClasspathJar works for me in win 11. Thank You.